# What should I do a potential supervisor doesn't reply after I send the research proposal to him?

Tags: phd, application

A potential suprvisor (British university) gave me a positive response after my first email, and asked me to send a more detailed research proposal to him. I send it to him on the 14th of July, and only received an automatic response from him.

> I will be back after 18th of July.

When time went to August, I still did not receive any response from him, so I sent him a follow-up email on the 3rd of August, but did not receive a reply yet, what should I do now?

Comment: Are you already admitted to the same university?

Comment: You say he said he will "return" in July, not that he will "reply" then. He may have needed a ping as your mail may be lost in a backlog catch up. You did that. Suggest a bit of patience.

Comment: It is summer, take it in mind

Answer (score 1):

You went on a date with a girl, but when you text her some time after that, she does not respond. What should you do? Well, there is nothing you *can* do -- she is not interested in your application to be her boyfriend, and that is that.

Now, is it rude to just "ghost" someone and not respond even with a "I'm not interested"? Maybe. But you can't really make someone talk to you if they don't want to.